# open cart journal2 theme product filters on mobile are not showed

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have a journal2 theme on opencart 2. I have a problem with product filters. On the desktop they are showing up normally and on mobile they are not loaded at all. Normally they should be rendered by $module variable in the left-column.tpl.

```
 <?php if ($modules) { ?>
<div id="column-left" class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs side-column <?php echo $this->journal2->settings->get('flyout_column_left_active') ? 'flyout-left' : ''; ?>">
 <?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
 <?php echo $module; ?>
 <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

But the filters module doesn't appear to get to the $module variable on mobile (the other modules are showing just fine also on mobile).

Can anyone give a clue how I to fix this? Where does $modules variable come from I mean the modules get added to it? What prevents filters to be rendered on mobile?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, I don't know how is that, but the problem was here:

```
in the /catalog/controller/module/journal2_super_filter.php
line 59
```

I found this line

```
if (Journal2Cache::$mobile_detect->isMobile() && !Journal2Cache::$mobile_detect->isTablet() && $this->journal2->settings->get('responsive_design')) return;
```

So indeed the filters didn't get rendered on mobiles... I have commented this line out and voila - I have my filters on mobile!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `hidden-xs` class.

This is a [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) class that hide content on small screens:

> Extra small devices Phones (<768px)

[Bootstrap CSS Helper Classes Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp)

Comment: Hi, This is not the problem. Filters do not load at all (the are not hidden by css). If the filter is the only one which sould appear in left column, column is not rendered at all, from which I conclude that the $modules array is empty... And this happens only on mobile...the very same page appears just fine on desktop.

Comment: can you send url if your site is live?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for a too late answer.... This site is not live. But I was able to find the problem - see the answer above. But anyway Thanks for trying to help! ;-)